# How to run FirebaseMessaging.configure() only once in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Flutter project I use Firebase Cloud Messaging package as follow:

```
var fbm = new FirebaseMessaging();
fbm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
```

So when notification arrives one of the options of configure method fires, that's working well. The problem is it's firing again if I restart the phone, or come back to current route that has this code. How can I delete arrived notification once it has been digested?

Comment: Add it to the constructor or `initState` of your root widget (then one you pass to `runapp(...)`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but at that stage I don't have access to context where bloc pattern is created, i need that